# Find first visible table row in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

If I have a table layout like so:

```
<table>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="three">
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="four">
    <td>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the easiest way to find the first showing row? I say this as some of the rows classes may have "display: none" set as part of a filtering process.

I thought that:

```
tr:first-child
```

Would work but it turns out it doesn't when hiding rows!

Comment: you will need to use javascript for this.

Comment: Every time I filter, call to check for the first row showing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `jQuery` it's simply:

```
$('tr:visible:first').foo();
```

You can't do it without javascript.

If speed is very important to you, this is a bit faster:

```
$('tr').filter(':visible').first().foo();
```

Docs:

> **Because :visible is a jQuery extension** and not part of the CSS specification, **queries using :visible cannot take advantage of the performance boost** provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :visible to select elements, **first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":visible").**